# Map values to formBuilder Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have some object like this

```
   const premises = [
      {
        question: '1',
        value: '1'
      },
      {
        question: '2',
        value: '2'
      },
      {
        question: '3',
        value: '3'
      }
    ];
```

I need to create something like this

```
this.formBuilder.group({
      1: [{ value: 1 }, [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100), Validators.required]],
      2: [{ value: 2 }, [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100), Validators.required]],
      3: [{ value: 3 }, [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100), Validators.required]]
    });
```

THis is just example, there can be as many values inside premises.

I have tried something like this

```
this.formBuilder.group({
      premises.forEach((x) => {
        x.question: [{ value: x.value }, [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100), Validators.required]]
      });
    });
```

But i didnt have luck how to create dinamic controls and values :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't return anything from a ForEach loop. It will return undefined by default.So using forEach will not work,
Instead use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create dynamic formControl object somethink like this

**Try this:**

```
let group = premises.reduce((acc, x) => {
   acc[x.question] = this.fb.control({ value: x.value, disabled: false }, [
    Validators.min(0),
    Validators.max(100),
    Validators.required,
  ]);
  return acc;
}, {});

this.formBuilder.group({
  ...group,
});
```

or

Use for loop to create dynamic object

```
let fGroup = {};
for (let i = 0; i < premises.length; i++) {
  fGroup[premises[i].question] = this.fb.control(
    { value: premises[i].value, disabled: false },
    [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100), Validators.required]
  );
}

 this.formBuilder.group({
  ...fGroup,
});
```

Comment: This is nice, but can you make some easier solution, thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer with for loop please check

Comment: Expected a 'for-of' loop instead of a 'for' loop with this simple iteration (prefer-for-of)t

Answer (score 0):

I would create a form array for this purpose. Premises is an array so using a FormArray with several functions like array `push` will be useful in such a data structure

```typescript
   const premises = [
      {
        question: '1',
        value: '1'
      },
      {
        question: '2',
        value: '2'
      },
      {
        question: '3',
        value: '3'
      }
    ];
this.formBuilder.group({
  premises: this.formBuilder.array(
    this.premises.map(premise => 
      this.formBuilder.group({ 
        value:[premise.value, [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100), Validators.required]]
    })
   )
)
```